# Kivy Text Input. Setting text with Clock.schedule_once()

Tags: kivy

I though that it will be fairly simple to show set some text to `TextInput` and show it on the screen but it seems I was wrong. In the below code I need to set text `Lorem ipsum...` to the text input and switch the tabs. I can see the text only when I uncomment `Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_text, 1)`. I would use `Clock.schedule_once` or any other way than just constantly calling `set_text()` method.

```
'''
Test of the widget TabbedPanel.
'''


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.factory import Factory

theRoot = """
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<EditButton>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Switch to Edit Screen'
        on_press: root.change_tab()

<EditInput>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
<UnCloseableHeader>
    color: 0,0,0,1

    disabled_color: self.color
    # variable tab_width
    text: 'tabx'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.texture_size[0] + 40
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        size_y: 20
        padding: 3
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: root.text

<MainTabbedPanel>:
    size_hint: (1, 1)
    do_default_tab: False
    #default_tab: edit_button_tab
    tab_width: 130

    FloatLayout:
        EditButton:
            id: edit_button
        EditInput:
            id: edit_input

    UnCloseableHeader:
        id: edit_button_tab
        text: 'Edit'
        content: edit_button.__self__

    UnCloseableHeader:
        id: edit_input_tab
        text: 'Edit Tab'
        content: edit_input.__self__

MainTabbedPanel:    

"""

class EditInput(BoxLayout):
    notes = ''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print('NOTES', self.notes)
        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.set_text, 1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_text, -1)

    def set_text(self, dt):
        print('SET TEXT', self.notes)
        self.ids.text_input.text = self.notes

class EditButton(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EditButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def change_tab(self):
        EditInput.notes = 'Lorem ipsum...'
        EditInput()

        mtp = App.get_running_app().root
        mtp.switch_to(mtp.ids.edit_input_tab)

class MainTabbedPanel(TabbedPanel):
    tab = ''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainTabbedPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tabs_showing = True


class UnCloseableHeader(TabbedPanelHeader):
    pass

Factory.register('UnCloseableHeader', cls=UnCloseableHeader)


sm = Builder.load_string(theRoot)

class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

**EDIT**

I've tried with:

**SNIPPET**

```
def change_tab(self):
    EditInput.notes = 'Lorem ipsum...'
    EditInput()
```

and:

```
Clock.schedule_once(self.set_text, 1)
```

It works in about 50% of cases witch is pretty hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Property` binding that `kv` sets up for you. Change your `EditInput` class to simply:

```
class EditInput(BoxLayout):
    notes = StringProperty('')
```

no need for any of the methods. Then, in your `kv`, change the `EditInput` rule to:

```
<EditInput>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TextInput:
        id: text_input
        text: root.notes
```

and change the `change_tab` method of `EditButton` to:

```
def change_tab(self):
    mtp = App.get_running_app().root
    mtp.ids.edit_input.notes = 'Lorem ipsum...'
    mtp.switch_to(mtp.ids.edit_input_tab)
```

Note that changing the `notes` property of the `EditInput` instance will automatically change the `TextInput` (due to the property binding set up by `kv`).

Also, the line in `change_tab()`:

```
EditInput()
```

is creating a new instance of the `EditInput` class that is unused and will be garbage collected.